# Django model query with Foreign key and get logged in user

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

Hi I am trying to add "fields" to my django projects that would be calculated based on query..

Basically I have 2 models one is a user which is an extension of Abstract user

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

and my main model is Project

```
class Project(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.PROTECT, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, editable=False)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, null=False, blank=False)
    this_month = datetime.datetime.now().month
    allprojectsthismonth = Project.objects.filter(created__month=this_month)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I create Project objects via a web form using this view:

```
def homepage(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        project = Project()
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        total = request.POST.get('total')
        created = datetime.datetime.now()
        user = request.user
        project.user = user
        project.name = name
        project.total = total
        project.created = created
        project.save()
        
        #return HttpResponse(reverse("homepage.views.homepage"))
        return render(request, 'homepage.html')
    else:

        return render(request, 'homepage.html')
```

What I need now is to have a queryset that gets me the combination of the total of a given user Project object so that I can make calculations on it, how would I go about doing that?

ideally I would get the logged in user and I could add to my view the sum of all Project.object.total with user = currently logged in.

Thanks

EDIT: Would this work?

```
class Project(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.PROTECT, editable=False)
name = models.CharField(max_length=20, editable=False)
total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, editable=False)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, null=False, blank=False)
this_month = datetime.datetime.now().month
projectsthismonth = self.objects.filter(created__month=this_month)

def monthlyTotal(self,request):
    projectsthismonth.objects.filter(
        user=request.user
    ).aggregate(
        sum_total=Sum('total')
    )['sum_total']
```

I seem to be missing something however.

Comment: You use `CustomUser` as user model (in `AUTH_USER_MODEL`)?

Comment: Yes my user model is working as well as Project it's just adding the features now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the queryset of the `Project`s where the user is the logged in user with:

```
Project.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

If you want to make simple aggregates (like sum, count, etc.), you better use [**`.aggregate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) since then the calculations are done at the database level. For example:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Project.objects.filter(
    user=request.user
).aggregate(
    sum_total=Sum('total')
)['sum_total']
```

will retrieve the sum of the `total`s of the `Project`s with `user=request.user`, this will be `None` if there are no projects related to the `user` at all.

```
from django.utils.timezone import now

class Project(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.PROTECT, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, editable=False)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, editable=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def monthlyTotal(self,user):
        this_month = now().month
        return Project.objects.filter(
            created__month=this_month,
            user=user
        ).aggregate(
            sum_total=Sum('total')
        )['sum_total']
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: Thank you for this! So would I write my queryset into the View directly? or the model?

Comment: @ThiMar: if is specific to a view in the view. If you will use the same logic in multiple views, then it belongs in the model layer.

Comment: I added an edit to my model  not sure if I am doing the right thing. Thanks for your help

Comment: @ThiMar: no, by using `this_month` at the class level, it will only be evaluated when the class is interpreted, so if you server starts today, after two days it will still use november. Furthermore models are normally *request-unaware*, so you use `user` as parameter, not `request`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation it makes much more sense to me now, and I have a path forward for this project. Greatly appreciated.